# How to get unlimited sweets after beating the game?

Tags: candy-box-2

I can access the "You won! You now have all the sweets in the world" with candy, lollipops, and chocolate falling, but don't know how to actually "get" them. Maybe because I'm on my phone and don't know where to click.. Little help, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the computer in the title bar at the top, and use it to input commands. The easiest way to get more candy is to type:

```
add x candies
```

Replace x with the number of candies you want, and replace candies with either:
`lollipops`,  `chocolatebars` or`painsauchocolat`.

The "You won!" screen doesn't actually do anything.